# PHP : How to get a specific value of an array

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the id of a specific value in my phpmyadmin table.
So, I have got a table with 'id_cal' as an A.I. id, 'mois' representing the month with numbers (e.g 1 for january) and 'annee' representing the year. (see [calendar table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XipE9.png))

I am trying to set php variable for the month and the year and if they match the current month and year, I want to get this specific id.

I commented the php code where I am having my trouble, here it is :

```
<?php

include_once('config.php');

$m = idate('n');
$y = idate('Y');

echo $m; echo "\t"; echo $y; echo "<br>"; echo "<br>";  // The result of this is 7 2019

$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM calendrier');

while($donnees= $reponse->fetch()){ 
    $mois = $donnees['mois'];
    $year = $donnees['annee'];
    $id_cal = $donnees['id_cal'];
    echo $id_cal;
    echo "\t";
    echo $mois;
    echo "\t";
    echo $year;
    echo "<br>";
}

// What I am trying to do :

if (($m = $mois) && ($y = $year)){  // If the month and the year are the current month/year
    $i = $id_cal;                   // I want to put the id refering to the current month/year (in my phpmyadmin table) into a new variable
    echo "<br>";                    // and echo this variable (or use it in other ways)
    echo $i;                        // BUT what I am echoing is 24 representing the number of values in my array
}                                   // How can I only get 7 ? (in this exemple, since we are the 7/2019)
```

Here is what I am getting in my localhost : [echo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWyuh.png)

I really don't understand why am I not having 7.

Also, I tried this instead of my while:

```
$donnees= $reponse->fetch();    
$mois = $donnees['mois'];
$year = $donnees['annee'];
$id_cal = $donnees['id_cal'];

// But in this cas I am having $i = 1, so it's the same problem.
```

Many thanks in advance for your response I am quite struggling with this.

Comment: Did you maybe want to put the `if` inside the loop?  The last time thru the loop `$id_cal` will equal the last one, which from your image is 24.

Comment: You also probably want `$m == $mois` instead of `$m = $mois`.

Comment: The == was indeed my main problem here and also putting the if statement in the loop helped me.
Thank you very much to both of you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `id_cal` gets overwritten with the new value of `id_cal` in each iteration of your while statement.

To get the result you want, you could put the if inside the while statement...

```
while($donnees= $reponse->fetch()){ 
    $mois = $donnees['mois'];
    $year = $donnees['annee'];
    $id_cal = $donnees['id_cal'];
    echo $id_cal;
    echo "\t";
    echo $mois;
    echo "\t";
    echo $year;
    echo "<br>";
    if (($m == $mois) && ($y == $year)){  
        $my_var_to_use_elsewhere = $id_cal;                 
    }   
}

echo "<br>";                   
echo $my_var_to_use_elsewhere;
```

Comment: This (with the add of Paul Spiegel solution, i.e the "==") worked perfectly, many thanks !

Comment: Ah yes of course!  You may also want to consider `break;` inside the if statement if you're not concerned with the values after your if statement is met. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php